# Why won't my door close after the hinge screws were tightened?

Tags: doors

My husband tightened the screws on the interior back door and now it won't close.  Hits on the know side.  What can I do?

Comment: Can you upload a picture?

Comment: Tightening the hinge screws should pull the door away from the knob side.  How did the door close before and where exactly does it hit?  Did he tighten top and bottom hinges?

Comment: More details, please. How long are the hinge screws? Is the jamb square with the wall? Yes, photos would be very helpful.

Comment: The door closed before.  He said he only tightened the bottom.  Once I'm off work I can send pictures

Comment: it just won't close it hits on the know side

Comment: Tightening the top screws will probably bring the door back into square/plumb with the jamb.  Imagine the door is hitting near the top of the knob side instead of the bottom or centre.

Comment: What's the "know" side? Google is giving me nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Tightening standard hinge screws won't cause a problem unless the jamb (door frame) was installed poorly to begin with. The hinges will always be square with the jamb and the door will close properly.

However, if the screws are actually *longer* than standard and run into the wall framing, the jamb could be pulled out of square. This would cause binding. The screws will need to be released, the jamb will need to be set properly, and the screws can then be snugged down again.

Other remote possibilities are that the hinges have been "sprung" (bent out of shape by excessive force), or that they're installed backwards.